# C++ inheritance function overriding

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

I have a question (part of my homework) which im unsure of the code's behavior.

I got a `class Father`, which owns a function "A", function "A" prints "Hello Father". 
I got a second class -> `class son:public Father`, which does not owns function "A". 
I got a third class -> `class grandson:public son` , which owns function "A" which prints "Hello grandson".

Function "A" is not virtual.
Please ignore compiling errors, I didnt want to put here a 80 lines of code.

I have another function :

```
void justPrint(const son& a) {
   a.A;
}
```

Now, what will be printed in the following call :

```
grandson jeff;
justPrint(jeff);
```

I'm a bit confused, son dont have the print function (A), so he suppose to call to Father::A (son is a father..) 
but, we send jeff (grandson) to the function which recieves son.. and grandson is a son..

I think that it will print

> "Hello Father"

But i'm so confused... Will appericiate any help and explenation..

Second thing, 
What will happen if i will make the following call :

```
justPrint(1);
```

Comment: Have you tried these to see the real outputs?

Comment: Actually `justPrint` function as described will not compile - or at least it won't call function `A`. And `justPrint(1)`, assuming there is only the function above also will not compile (as `1` is not a valid class `son` object).

Comment: And to be able to answer the question (ignoring errors mentioned above), we need to know if function `A` in the class `father` is virtual or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to make a short code to solve your problem, but I don't have it (using "g++  test.cpp -fpermissive" to compile)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Father
{
    public:
    void A(){
        cout<<"Hello Father"<<endl;
    }
};

class Son : public Father
{
};

class GrandSon : public Son
{
    public:
    void A()
    {
        cout<<"Hello GrandSon"<<endl;
    }
};

void justPrint(const Son& a)
{
    a.A();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    GrandSon jeff;
    justPrint(jeff);
    return 0;
}
```

Maybe you have put A in private?

---

Output:
Hello Father

Comment: Hi, This is what i think it should print (as you can see in my answer), But I was not sure.

Comment: It's because you have use  "class Son : public Father" to build Son. So Son have have all public methode that Father have (include A()).
Morover, Son don't have a A(), so it use the heritance tree, and take the first one "A" (here in Father::A) with the same signature.

Answer (score 0):

```
void justPrint(const son& a) {
   a.A;
}

justPrint(1); if Class son contains single argument constructor with int as i/p.It will call that .
```

Comment: class son does contains a single argument constructor.
Can you please explain me why it will be called ?

Comment: It will be called if it takes an int, unless you mark it explicit